# JavaFX - Bind ButtonAction to ComboBox Item

Tags: java, button, javafx, combobox, enter

I'm using an editable ComboBox called `testBox` with the items `testBox.getItems().addAll("A","B","C");`. 
I also have an on Enter-Event

```
@FXML
public void onEnter(ActionEvent event){
//
}
```

And ButtonEvents like

```
@FXML
void aButton(ActionEvent event){
//Do stuff
}
@FXML
void bButton(ActionEvent event){
//Do stuff
}
@FXML
void cButton(ActionEvent event){
//Do stuff
}
```

How can i fire for example my button 'a'-event when the 'a'-item is selected and Enter pressed?

Please add snippets :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could determine the action to be executed in the event handler. E.g. assuming the items list is not modified:

```
List<EventHandler<ActionEvent>> handlers = Arrays.asList(
                                                    this::aButton,
                                                    this::bButton,
                                                    this::cButton
    );

@FXML
public void onEnter(ActionEvent event){
    int index = testBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    if (index >= 0) {
         handlers.get(index).handle(event);
    }
}
```

You could of course also use a item type that contains a property for the handler...

Comment: So far it works, but the first time I select an item, it fires the first item in my list. It only fire the right action if I choose the item from the drop down list. I have to add that my List filters items while typing.